# Change port of wordpress

Tags: http

I am trying to change the port of wordpress to 9000. I am using LAMP server. I tried by changing the wp_options table,the settings options and changing in the wp-config.php file. It's showing unable to connect.

Answer (score -1):

@annie you should change both siteurl and home option_name values to e.g http://localhost/wordpress:9000

Comment: have tried that but didn't work

Comment: Please check your apache logs and post the latest here

Comment: only in the siteurl and home we need to change or anywhere else? will post my apache log soon

Comment: That is what the codex says. https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: yeah...i saw the article...but its not working

Comment: AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace. this is the apache log

Comment: Could you add `define( 'define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );` in your wp-config to see if there is some output? I do not know the reason yet

Comment: i could change the port by altering the listening port of apache  from 80 to 9000 and  by changing the siteurl and home but not sure if its the right way.

Comment: Give it a try and see